# Can my teacher require minors to apply for a quote to complete an assignment?

Tags: utah

My teacher gave us an assignment where we need to compare auto insurance plans from different companies. It needs to be based off what we need/want. This sounds impossible to do without getting a quote from all the insurance companies since I cannot find pricing information online. Isn't it illegal for a teacher to make students (especially minors) give other sites/source their personal information for an assignment?

Comment: Is it a requirement to use accurate information?

Comment: She wants accurate information yes. I need to provide information about deductibles, premiums etc for the plans that I compare that are based on the same provided information.

Comment: So use the same fake information. The point is consistency and validity, and to let you learn the process  as a hypothetical situation before you need to do it for real, not make you actually apply for insurance for yourself.

Comment: Many insurance company tools will provide a quote for a fake applicant and compare it to competitors.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I bought mine, so I'm not sure if they ask for SSNs.  In the United States, you cannot be compelled to use your SSN for anything that other than Social Security purposes.  Private companies can do it, because you're not being compelled to do buisness with them.  Government cannot, so you could in theory refuse (as an employer this is another matter, because, you're not being forced to apply to a government job.).  Seeing as this is compelling you to use your SSN to get a grade, it could be a violation.

To get around this without a legal fight, call up a sales person for the companies that you are researching and explain the situation:  You're doing this for an assignment and not actual purchase, and you just want to get a quote without giving Personal Information out.

I would also inform your parents or legal guardians about this assignment (I'm assuming you're not 18 yet) because they can get attention of principals or administrators better, but don't hesitate to inform such facualty yourself and raise your concerns.

I'm not sure which organisation would be best to help out with this matter, but there are things like Campus Reform which do work to protect student's rights.  Campus Reform is a conservative organization best known for fighting for Free Speech rights on college campuses and reporting on alleged classroom political propaganda from educators, so I'm not sure if this is their wheelhouse, but they could be a good springboard and they might even be able to direct you to another org that this is suited for.

Try holding off on involving the lawyers as much as you can, and make a good effort to comply without giving out any information you don't feel comfortable with.  If you do go through with doing it online, make sure that the URL contains the letters HTTPS at all times as the first five letters.  If at any time a page does not contain those five leters (Specifically the "S", for Secure) do not enter any info into any box, close the site down, and note the issue.  Firefox makes this easier by having an image of a green lock right next to the URL if and only if the URL contains HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't it illegal for a teacher to make students (especially minors)
>   give other sites/source their personal information for an assignment?

No.

You sometimes have a right to not have private information that has been provided to a business by you shared with other businesses.

You do not, in general, have a right to never disclose personal information to anyone (and for what it is worth, you already disclosed to the school all of the personal information that would be used in the assignment).

None of the information which must be provided to obtain a car insurance quote is privileged from disclosure.